# How to call the linux command "source FILE_NAME" from Java?

Tags: java, linux

Actually I have two commands :

1. source FILE_NAME
2. Install ABCD

Before executing the second command, i need to execute the first one. I tied to execute both the command using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)` methos, but second command failed, since it depends on the first one. I tried many combinations, but not succeeded. Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Consider ProcessBuilder

Comment: Plz elaborate, how to use two commands simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably executing two separate exec commands, spawning separate processes, and so whatever you do in the first process is not visible to the second. Resolve this by putting all of your commands into a script (bash, ksh, etc) and call it once from your Java program.

Paramterize your script so you can pass arguments.

Here's some help on [writing your first shell script](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-kornshellscripting/)

---

**[Edit]** As mentioned by @RNJ you can look at using [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to pass in environment variables to each of the processes spawned. This will be fine if you can specify the name of the file being created ahead of time. Example code taken from the API link above...

```
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
 Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
 env.put("VAR1", "myValue");
 env.remove("OTHERVAR");
 env.put("VAR2", env.get("VAR1") + "suffix");
 pb.directory(new File("myDir"));
 Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: Is there any other way, through the java class files only?

Comment: Your question is very clear on what is is your trying to achieve. I have assumed you want to create a file and then pass in the file path to that file to your second process.

Comment: thanks @Brad, it worked. I am now manually putting all the environment variables using ProcessBuilder.